# Custom SharePoint Designer (SPD) workflow activity sentence not visible in SPD

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I created a custom workflow activity (action) for SharePoint Designer. I deployed the assembly to the GAC, added the  entry in the web.config file and created a .ACTIONS file in the 12hive (sub)folder.
When I now open SPD and create a new workflow I can see my workflow action but when I select it the "sentence" is not shown. I checked it all but cannot find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Download the sourcecode and config-files [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9346580/CustomSPDAction.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this! Essentially I was updating the wrong web.config file; needed to update the one that sits on port 80.

For me this was here:

```
\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80
```

I was udpating the one here:

```
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\CONFIG
```

Not sure why I picked that one; maybe because it was nearby the templates and other stuff I was editing.

Found the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/4e7a77f4-c29b-47b2-a1de-79470f0bb1c9 (hate to steal credit :-P)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything blatantly wrong. Have you tried [clearing your proxy assembly cache](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/troubleshoot-workflow-errors-HA010237912.aspx#BM48)?